# Mallet dirichelet parameter higher than 1

Tags: machine-learning, lda, topic-modeling, mallet

I've been using MALLET in order to perform my topic modeling(LDA).

I tried to discover 20 topics in a dataset
The outcome is the following (the list of keywords is not important for this question):

```
0   0.05013 list_of_topic_keywords_0
1   0.06444 list_of_topic_keywords_1
2   0.04946 list_of_topic_keywords_2
3   0.14458 list_of_topic_keywords_3
4   0.09248 list_of_topic_keywords_4
5   0.04865 list_of_topic_keywords_5
6   0.0977  list_of_topic_keywords_6
7   0.0653  list_of_topic_keywords_7
8   0.04557 list_of_topic_keywords_8
9   0.07494 list_of_topic_keywords_9
10  0.03577 list_of_topic_keywords_10
11  0.02867 list_of_topic_keywords_11
12  0.04184 list_of_topic_keywords_12
13  0.05251 list_of_topic_keywords_13
14  0.04231 list_of_topic_keywords_14
15  0.03207 list_of_topic_keywords_15
16  0.13064 list_of_topic_keywords_16
17  0.04922 list_of_topic_keywords_17
18  1.0515  list_of_topic_keywords_18
19  0.04922 list_of_topic_keywords_19
```

I've read that the second number in each row (e.g. 0.05013  in row 0) represents the dirichlet parameter. I thought this number represented the importance of the topic (the presence throughout the documents) and I believed the total should sum op to 1.

However this is not the case! By only looking at topic 18, which has a value of 1.0515.

Could someone explain me what this parameter really represents and why it's higher than 1 for a particular topic?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Because parameters to a Dirichlet are constrained to be positive reals. They're not proportions. *Samples* from a Dirichlet are proportions (it has support on the simplex).

First place to check: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_distribution

Size does reflect relative importance. If you normalise a particular parameter by the sum over the Dirichlet parameters, you'll get the expected value of the proportion, but don't make the mistake of thinking this is what the proportion is.